# How to add image to left of text view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

I want to add the image to the left of text view so that the text written in text view should go below the image when it reach to it's right maximum width.I know this i very easy to do in HTML but how to do it in iOS?

Comment: You can try to use [CoreText](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBoQFjAAahUKEwje08OlybzIAhXl4aYKHXrOAJA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FStringsTextFonts%2FConceptual%2FCoreText_Programming%2FIntroduction%2FIntroduction.html&usg=AFQjCNH6AkhZzx73EjZhLYRaa7YpEHOFug) and use a CGPath to draw your text. Here are a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app).

Comment: In Xcode, you can't really do that with one item. One solution is to create a textView and an imageView individually, then merge the two together with aligning and margins in auto layout.

Comment: if i merge i want to set text of uitextview when uiimage view ends